# Azure SWA Development - Accessing Storage during local development

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-static-web-app

I'm developing an SWA app and would like for an API in my app to access Azure Storage.
Ultimately, I'd prefer to use a Managed Entity for this.

I am using AD authentication, but when developing locally, the emulator is used.

When developing locally, how can I access actual Azure resources? Do I need to resort to keys and managing the credentials directly? Can I leverage the azure login, even though the emulator is in use?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating one sample SWA app and ran it locally with emulator. Unfortunately you cannot authenticate with Azure resources with emulator as emulator will just mock the similar behaviour of Azure storage account in the storage emulator. And if you want to authenticate with Azure storage account you need to refer the steps [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host).

*I have referred the steps from this [**github repository**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/local-development.md).*

Ran the **`vanilla swa app`** locally with **`storage emulator`**:-

```js
 npm install @azure/static-web-apps-cli
 npx swa init
 npx swa start
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Add this line to connect your app with Azure AD as identity provider referred from [**here**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization.md)

```http
[Azure Static Web Apps Emulator - Authentication Portal](http://localhost:4280/.auth/login/aad)

.auth/login/aad
```

[image]

But if you want to run Azure commands from Storage emulator CLI terminal that is possible, Download the storage emulator from this [**link**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/) and run `az login` command like below :-

This will connect to your azure resources like normal az cli command line tool. If you want your static web app to access the azure resources you need to implement authentication in your application source code with Azure AD.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not interested in a static site served from Storage. I have moved on to using AD auth in my functions using DefaultAzureCredential.